# axios keeps removing question mark for query string

Tags: axios

Here's my axios config:

```
const axiosApi = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL
})

axiosApi.interceptors.response.use(
  response =>
    response
  ,
  error => {
    if (error.response.status === 404) {
      throw new Error(`404\nService does not exist\n${error.request.path}`)
    }
  }
)

export async function get(url) {
  console.log(url)
  return await
    axiosApi.get(url, {
      crossDomain: true
    }).then(response => {
      return response?.data
    })
}
```

The problem is that when I try to get `/path?key=value`, I get the `/pathkey=value does not exist` error.

While `console.log(url)` shows me the true URL with the question mark and query string, the response interceptor strips the question mark out and that causes 404.

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 6):

This is an Axios bug in v1.0.0

- Issue reported here: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4999
- Fixed in [v1.1.0](https://github.com/axios/axios/releases/tag/v1.1.0)

Answer (score 2):

You should pass the query params like below:

```
axios.get('/path', { params: { key: value} });
```

Comment: The query string is as simple as `?key=contactUs`. It does not contain special characters in it.

Comment: I also did that using `encodeURI` and `encodeURIComponent` methods, but I still get that error of 404.

Comment: The answer has been updated.

Comment: I just realized that colleagues upgraded axios to `1.0.0` which is released 10 hours ago. I thing I need to refactor a lot of code. This code was working beforehand. I could send a complete path and query in one string. Now I should split them? That's so sad.

Comment: But in their [official docs](https://axios-http.com/docs/example) they also use a string for path and query. So that should not be the problem.

Comment: Yep, it worked. It seems that Axios does not accept a string as the URL anymore. We need to split path and query.

Comment: @Bigboy I just saw the official docs as well, not sure why they put the query string directly in the URL. It is always a good habit to put params in an object

Comment: @Bigboy See Dawid's answer, it is an issue introdcued in axios v1.0.0

Answer (score 2):

Try limit the version in dependency.

"dependencies": {
"axios": "~0.27.2",
},

may help.

Personally I don't even get why Axios developer decide to do this.

Basically according to HTTP Protocol both path and query parameters is considered URI.

Axios.get() should accept everything that is considered URI to conform with HTTP specifications.

And project which let user input its URL for fetch the data will just broken out of the box.